# How to animate an element off another element with CSS without having to keep holding the click

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have a table, which contains a number of 'clickable' rows in ReactJS.

Each row, when you hover over it, will get slightly shaded - and arrow icon will appear in a little box that fades in from the left using traditional CSS animations/transitions.

What I want to accomplish, is that when you click on the row, the icon that appeared will essentially continue on its path and fade out to the right.

I have the code written below, and if you click and hold the row once hovered in, you will see that the arrow does move out. However, if you release the click, the functionality basically halts [as expected with an `:active pseudoclass`].

Is it possible to do this such that when you click a row, the element floats off without relying on the `:active` psuedo? Is this possible without JavaScript?

```css
table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-indent: initial;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.table > thead > tr > th {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0;
}

table td {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 20px;
}

.table.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

tr.has-click-handler {
  cursor: pointer;
}
tr.has-click-handler:hover td {
  background-color: rgba(10, 138, 241, 0.192);
}
tr.has-click-handler td.row-click-indicator {
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
tr.has-click-handler td.row-click-indicator:after {
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  content: ">";
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 900;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #004990;
  color: #fff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
tr.has-click-handler td.row-click-indicator:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 10px;
}
tr.has-click-handler td.row-click-indicator:active:after {
  right: -25px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-right pr-2">#</th>
      <th>Class Name</th>
      <th class="text-right">Meta Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="has-click-handler">
      <td class="text-right pr-2">1.</td>
      <td class="row-click-indicator">Auth Security</td>
      <td align="right"><span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">7</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="has-click-handler">
      <td class="text-right pr-2">2.</td>
      <td class="row-click-indicator">Data Storage</td>
      <td align="right"><span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">5</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="has-click-handler">
      <td class="text-right pr-2">3.</td>
      <td class="row-click-indicator">Data Receiving </td>
      <td align="right"><span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">5</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="has-click-handler">
      <td class="text-right pr-2">4.</td>
      <td class="row-click-indicator">Data Integrity</td>
      <td align="right"><span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="has-click-handler">
      <td class="text-right pr-2">5.</td>
      <td class="row-click-indicator">Vulnerabilities</td>
      <td align="right"><span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="has-click-handler">
      <td class="text-right pr-2">6.</td>
      <td class="row-click-indicator">Network</td>
      <td align="right"><span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">0</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update**

I should state, I would like a non-javascript solution if at all possible. Is there a way to initiate a `transition` with CSS and have it keep going regardless of the current state of the element? (hover/active/focus)

Answer (score 0):

Use can use JavaScript for this.
Use JavaScript `onMouseOver`, `onMouseDown`, or use `EventListeners` for this to achieve.
And use this snippet to understand better.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1 id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">HOVER ME</h1>

  <script>
    function mouseOver() {
      document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "#799";
    }

    function mouseOut() {
      document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "black";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not quite what I am looking for, I would prefer no javascript. Ideally, a CSS only solution that basically starts an animation and finishes it - so it doesnt stop if the behavior is removed